# XCeed WPF Toolkit DatePicker in C# not correct

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed, datapicker

I use a Datepicker from Extended XCeed Toolkit in some Windows.

It seems to work fine, but I run the following problem:

I change the date using calender selection.

I dump the value in my code behind and it happens:

in my code behind the value is only changed, when I go backwords to a different month. If I then go forward to the actual month, the value ist the first day of the month, even if I choose the actual day.

Has anybody experienced the same?

What could be wrong in my code?

I tried to fire "source updated" event, but this did not help.
my code

my code behind

```
            var isoDateTimeFormat = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat;
        string ttt = dpInvErfassen.DisplayDate.ToString(isoDateTimeFormat.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern).Substring(0, 10);
```

and the XAML is

```
        <DatePicker x:Name="dpInvErfassen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="288" Canvas.Top="4" SourceUpdated="dpInvErfassen_SourceUpdated"/>
```

I feel, with that code I do nothing strange